# Check if email can receive iMessages

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6, imessage

You are able to configure your iPhone to be able to receive iMessages send to your email. Also  iPod Touches and iPads can receive iMessages send to emails.

Given an email address is it possible to check, if this address is able to receive an iMessage?

Apple is doing this in the Messages app to change the send button color, I would like to implement something similar.

Answer (score 0):

No, Apple have not released any API for iMessage. You can only check if the device can send an message, with [`MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html) method.